# weird result for circle detection using opencv's HoughCircles()

Tags: opencv

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(pimg,(3,3),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 30, 55)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur[:,:,0],cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,8,param1=10,param2=55,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

Above is my code, how I use the function, link ([sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Nh7TaS6iJlbGp3LTkzV3U3WVE/edit?usp=sharing)) is my results. from left to right, is the original figure, result and edges. The results( green circles) do not match the input at all. :( What mistakes I have done here, please share your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: in your image nothing looks like circle..I think HoughCircle is not that power-full enough to identify the circle you are looking for in your image.

Comment: you need to change  adjust the parameter of you houghcircle function and maybe the filtering as well and google cv:termCriteria it may help you augmenting the acurracy of the recognition.

by seeing your image, you need definitely to make the max radius a bit smaller